# Radicial Morphism over DVR's

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I would like a reference for the truth/falsity of the following statement:

Suppose that $X \rightarrow Y$ is a map of $S$ schemes where $S$ is the spectrum of a DVR with generic point $\eta$ and closed point $x$. Suppose that $f_{\eta}:X_{\eta} \rightarrow Y_{\eta}$ is radicial and $f_{x}: X_{x} \rightarrow Y_{x}$ is radicial, then $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is radicial.

One can verify that injectivity on underlying spaces can be checked on fibers, but I am not sure about the "purely inseparability" condition.

Many thanks